# Generate all permutations in Clojure

Tags: beginner, functional-programming, combinatorics, clojure

Given a set, generate all permutations:

```
(permutations #{1 4 5}) => ((5 4 1) (4 5 1) (5 1 4) (1 5 4) (4 1 5) (1 4 5))
```

Here's what I cobbled together:

```
(defn perm-r [allPerms currentPerm input i]
  (cond
    (empty? input) (conj allPerms currentPerm)
    (< i 0) allPerms
    :else (perm-r
            (perm-r
              allPerms
              (conj currentPerm (nth input i))
              (remove (fn [x] (= x (nth input i))) input)
              (dec
                (count
                  (remove
                    (fn [x] (= x (nth input i)))
                    input))))
            currentPerm
            input
            (dec i))))

(defn permutations [a-set]
  (perm-r `() `() (seq a-set) (dec (count a-set))))
```

I thought my solution was awful, so I went to look for other solutions and found [this](https://github.com/tleht/recursion/blob/bc8c93237febfc415a4dd354ad0d26dac2e604a5/src/recursion.clj):

> ```
> (defn rotations [a-seq]
>   (distinct (map concat (tails a-seq) (inits a-seq))))
>
> (defn permutations [a-set]
>   (if (empty? a-set)
>     (list ())
>     (apply concat (map (fn [x] (map cons (repeat (first x))
>                                          (permutations (rest x))))
>                   (rotations a-set)))))
> ```

It looks so elegant! I'm not used to functional programming, so I find the execution flow immensely difficult to follow. In particular, I don't understand what's being concatenated. Is the result of the first `map` call (which represents what exactly?) to every rotation of a-set?

Any tips on improving my thought process so that I could come up with a solution like that on my own? I'm used to programming imperatively and I don't find functions like `map` or `apply` intuitive. Is there a way to make this function more readable or improve it further in other ways?

Comment: There are many ways of doing it.  If you would like to see a very effective implementation, please look at the source for https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's clean the code up a bit.

Function `tails` gives us all the possible ending sub-sequences. For example ...

```
(tails (range 3)) ; ((0 1 2) (1 2) (2) ())
```

And `inits` gives us all the initial sub-sequences. For example ...

```
(inits (range 3)) ; (() (0) (0 1) (0 1 2))
```

To get the rotations, we marry the `init` with the corresponding `tail`,using `concat`. If we just

```
(defn rotations [a-seq]
  (map concat (tails a-seq) (inits a-seq)))
```

`
... then we get the original sequence at both ends:

```
(rotations (range 5)) ; ((0 1 2 3 4) (1 2 3 4 0) (2 3 4 0 1) (3 4 0 1 2) (4 0 1 2 3) (0 1 2 3 4))
```

The given code uses `distinct` to get rid of the duplicate. It's faster and simpler to use `rest`:

```
(defn rotations [a-seq]
  (rest (map concat (tails a-seq) (inits a-seq))))
```

Now

```
(rotations (range 5)) ; ((1 2 3 4 0) (2 3 4 0 1) (3 4 0 1 2) (4 0 1 2 3) (0 1 2 3 4))
```

And we're ready to generate all the permutations. We can rewrite the given code as follows:

```
(defn permutations [a-set]
  (if (empty? a-set)
    (list ())
    (mapcat
     (fn [[x & xs]] (map #(cons x %) (permutations xs)))
     (rotations a-set))))
```

- `(mapcat f coll)`is an abbreviation for `(apply concat (map f coll))`.
- `(fn [[x & xs]] ... )` is a *destructuring* form that sets `x` to the
  `first` and `xs` to the `rest` of its sequence argument.
- `#(cons x %)` is an abbreviation for `(fn [y] (cons x y))`, a
  function that puts `x` on the front of its sequence argument.

For every rotation of the given set, the `permutations` function glues its first element onto each permutation of the rest of the elements, and then concatenates all these collections together. For example ...

```
(permutations (range 3))
; ((1 0 2) (1 2 0) (2 1 0) (2 0 1) (0 2 1) (0 1 2))
```

That's it.

---

The given `inits` ...

```
(defn inits [a-seq]
  (reverse (map reverse (tails (reverse a-seq)))))
```

... is somewhat overworked, on account of all the `reverse`s. A neater way to get the `rotations` is

```
(defn rotations [a-seq]
  (let [a-vec (vec a-seq)]
    (for [i (range (count a-vec))]
      (concat (subvec a-vec i) (subvec a-vec 0 i)))))
```

Comment: Where is `tails` defined?

Comment: I too figured `tails` would be in `clojure.core`, but it's simple enough to do `(defn tails [coll] (take-while seq (iterate rest coll)))`

Comment: Also inits could be written as `(defn inits [coll] (reductions conj [] coll)) `